# How to add the table td text into progress values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have progress bars in the third column of my table.

And I want to replace the amount of each progress in each row base on  numbers in first and two columns of table each row .

How can I do this with jQuery ?

For example :

I want to put 30 instead of max in progress bar also put 4 instead of my value in progress bar.

Here is my code :

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>30</td>
<td>4</td>
<td> <progress value="98" max="100"><div id="progress" class="graph"></div></progress></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td>6</td>
<td> <progress value="50" max="100"><div id="progress" class="graph"></div></progress></td>
</tr>


</table>
```

Comment: can you give an example ? in first row the numbers are 30 and 4, what do you want the progress value to be ?

Comment: @mrid i want to put 30 instead of max in progress bar also put 4 insted of my value i progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select `progress` element using `td:eq(2)` and then set its `value` to text of second `td` element in row and `max` property value from first `td` in row.

```js
$("table tr").each(function() {
  var progress = $(this).find('td:eq(2) progress');
  progress.val($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text())
  progress.prop('max', $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>30</td>
<td>4</td>
<td> <progress value="98" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td>6</td>
<td> <progress value="50" max="100"><div class="graph"></div></progress></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It's jquery selector that selects element by index https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/, you can also use `nth-child` in this case but then it starts from 1.

Comment: he's selecting the first td of the row and using it as progressbar max value

Comment: @aynaz It starts from 0 so first `td` has index of 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have `<div id="progress" ...>` in both table rows.

**An id should be used only once on a page.**

So either change the ids or use just use class.

```js
$('#table1 tr').each(function(){
    var row = $(this);
    var tds = row.find('td');
    tds[2].innerHTML = '<progress value="' + tds[1].innerHTML + '" max="' + tds[0].innerHTML + '"><div class="graph"></div></progress>';
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="table1">
<tr>
<td>30</td>
<td>4</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>20</td>
<td>6</td>
<td> </td>
</tr>


</table>
```